# How do ensure my .jar is reading data from within the standalone file

Tags: java, csv, clojure, leiningen

I have a program which is required to read a csv file prior to running. This data was located within a resource folder within my clojure project.

The program ran fine, when slurping from `"resources/data.cv"` however this results in the `.jar` not being standalone, but requiring the resources folder.

How do I ensure that the resources are also compiled when I run `lein uberjar`?

I have tried `(csv/slurp-csv (io/resource "mma_duffing.csv")` however the .jar file then won't run. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you manage to read the file if you do `(println (slurp (io/resource "mma_duffing.csv")))` ?

Comment: io-resources work slightly different when running from a jar, the resource will have a protocol like: `jar:file:/blablabla/bla.jar!/data.csv`.. If the csv library here uses a custom file-reader of some sort it might not know how to handle this protocol.. Check the source code of the csv-library and see what it does to access the file.

Comment: tried this minus `println`, as I don't require it, and it worked fine. Not too sure what was going wrong but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you put your file into the resources directory you can then read it when both doing lein run and when running the jar by using something like this code:

`(defn read-resource
  []
  (slurp (.getResource (ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader) "mydatafile")))`

Hope that works for you...